# Multiplas chamadas ao modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom dia.

Ao clicar em um botão, esse botão chama um modal, cujo essa chamada acontece duas vezes, e não consigo entender o porque essa chamada está vindo duas vezes como vocês podem ver na imagem a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Chamada do model**

```
<p>
    <a href="#" id="btnDistribuir" class="btn btn-success" data-action="Distribui" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Distribuir Pedidos para Operação'>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        Registro | Cadastrar | Create
    </a>
</p>
```

**Código do model que está com erro**

```
@model PortalLatam.Models.PedidosModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Distribuir Documentos";
}

<h2>Distribuir Documentos para Operação</h2>

<style>
    .modal .modal-dialog {
        width: 60%;
    }
</style>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Distribuir</title>

</head>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cmbColaboradores">Colaboradores</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="cmbColaboradores"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input class="checkbox-inline" type="checkbox" name="chkSelecionaTodos" id="chkSelecionaTodos" />
                    <span>Selecionar todos</span>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-xs-12'>
                <div class="col-xs-1">#</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">Número do Protocolo </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">Data do Protocolo </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">Colaborador </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">BP </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div id="pedidos">



            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGravar" name="btnGravar" value="Gravar" />
            </div>

        </div>



    </div>




    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/projeto/EnviarFormulario.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Projeto/DistribuiPedidoLatam.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var btnAcao = $("input[type='button']");
        var formulario = $("#formCrud");

    </script>
```

Comment: A pergunta ficou bem dificil de entender... não entendi o que você precisa, e você diz "Código do model que está com erro", que model? o correto não seria View ?

Comment: Sim, seria uma view chamada em modal, não model rs

Comment: Coloque o script da chamada do modal e inclua o código do modal

Comment: A chamada do modal está ali e código do modal também

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa identificar os eventos associados ao botão que estão disparando o evento que abre a modal.

Tem diversas formas de fazer isso, a mais simples é usando as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador, que tem suporte para isso.

Pegando o *Google Chrome* por exemplo, ao acionar a ferramenta e inspecionar um elemento (creio que você saiba como fazer isso, usando <kbd>F12</kbd>), na aba "Elements" tem outra aba chamada "Event Listeners". Clicando lá você vai visualizar todos os *listeners* associados, ou seja, todos os códigos que fazem abrir a modal, e vai poder identificar que está duplicado.

Veja o exemplo na figura abaixo, que peguei os eventos "click" associados à imagem de *upvote* aqui do site:

[image: inspecionar elemento]

Assim vai conseguir identificar que está acionando o click, e achar o código duplicado.

Se quiser algo mais elaborado, instale a extensão "Visual Event" do *Google Chrome* que traz uma visão mais clara ainda dos eventos: [chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visual-event/pbmmieigblcbldgdokdjpioljjninaim?hl=pt-BR)

Comment: Muuuuito obrigado, achei onde estava duplicado.